# How to run an npm script without triggering update check

Tags: npm

Is there command line option to use `npm run-script ...` without triggering an update check?

I ask because I am using [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run two scripts. Often, but not always, I get a "npm update check failed" error message and (I believe) this is because both invocations of node are trying to access the `.config` store concurrently.

Relevant part of `package.json`

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm:start-browser\" \"npm:start-server\"",
    "start-browser": "node start-browser.js",
    "start-server": "node index.mjs",
  },
```

and I run this with `npm start`.

I am using node 14.15.1 and npm 6.14.8, on Windows 10.

The full text of the error is

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                  npm update check failed                   │
│            Try running with sudo or get access             │
│            to the local update config store via            │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\pedro\.config │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Note: I never see this error when running other npm scripts, only the one with `concurrently`, that's why I think it's something to do with concurrent access to `.config`

(edit) Here is a minimal package.json which will show the error (for me, about 25% of the time)

```json
{
  "name": "coco",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently npm:start-1 npm:start-1",
    "start-1":"node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.0.2"
  }
}
```

and index.js is

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

Note: I still get the error if I run in a Windows **Administrator** Power Shell

Comment: which command-line tool you are using ?

Comment: npm. I have made an edit which will hopefully answer your question, @ShubhamPatel

Comment: have tried, sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\pedro\.config (granting ownership) to .config file

Comment: I never understood why npm makes that suggestion - sudo, chown, id etc. are all Unix things and not on Windows. However I have confirmed that I have ownership of .config and its contents using the Windows UI.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the CLI and also try to open CLI with the administrator. I am saying this is the perfect solution, but for debugging purposes you can try running CLI as administrator. (this should suppress this error)

Comment: I don't know why you need a screenshot, but anyway I have confirmed it still happens when run as administrator and I made a minimal package.json.